# Sample application N-Layer Architecture with EF 4.0 and Webforms

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I am looking for a sample architecture for multi layer architecture with asp.net webforms 4.0 and Entity framwork 4.0.

I don't want to use WCF services. So If any one have any good link about it. Then please suggest me.

Thanks in advance for your replies.

Best Regards,

Jalpesh

Answer (score 1):

NerdDinner has all the new stuff:

http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/

From their site:

**Here's what we're working on:**

- Mvc 3 + Razor - added
- EF Code First (for a database that already exists!) - added
- All libraries via NuGet - added
- YepNope with Modernizr - added
- JQuery Mobile beta 2 - added, some back button issues
- An updated MobileCapableRazorViewEngine fixing a nasty caching
  bug Scott introduced a few years back
- This probably needs to be tested some more then Pete and I
  will make it a NuGet package for MVC3. MVC4 will have formal support
  for mobile views baked in.
- Geolocation, both desktop and mobile - added, some mobile work
  needed
- MvcHtml5Templates by Scott Kirkland - added
- ELMAH (and MiniProfiler to come soon) - almost done
- 51Degrees Mobile capabilities module - added
- DotNetOpenAuth by Andrew Arnott - added
     proper Web Deploy Transforms - added
- OpenID - added
- Support all Countries - added
- Exploit Virtual Earth's APIs more - added "draggable pins"
- RSS Feeds for all pages - added a main one, need more?
- iCal downloads for all events - added an iCal feed, and iCal for
  each details
- "My" Dinners - added
- Mobile version of the site - added
- Twitter integration? Facebook integration? - Added Facebook,
  Twitter, sharing
- Blog Badges showing nearby dinners with automatic geo-location. -
  Added Flair, updating with cleaner implementation
- As many Tests and as much Coverage as we can stomach - need
  volunteers
- Continuous Integration Server - almost done. Thanks JetBrains!

Answer (score 0):

Someone had taken the time to create such an app.  It's available at http://www.dofactory.com.  I found it some time ago when I was researching a pattern.  Here, http://www.dofactory.com/Framework/Framework.aspx,  they provide pretty descriptive detail regarding their design.  It does have WCF but it looks like that would be pretty easy to strip out.  Lastly the catch, it's $79 USD.  I have not seen the code so I could not tell you if it's worth it or not.  If you do buy it, please comment so others will have feedback from an actual user of the code.

Comment: I forgot about NerdDinner, that would be a good one.  Great suggestion Rick.  Scott Hanselman and his team are wicked smart who provide lots of info for free.  NerdDinner goes waaay beyond codeplex, just do a search and you'll find lots of videos.  Or you can google Scott Hanselman and you'll find more additional good stuff.